# Why am I getting error nested too deeply for this linq SQL query?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

```
// Note serialNumbers is a List<string 
var ids = (from i in DB.InventoryItems
           join s in serialNumbers on i.SerialNumber equals s
           select i.id);
return string.Join(",", ids);
```

The `serialNumbers` variable is a list of type string. I am getting error after about 100 items are included in this `serialNumbers` list

Comment: What's the error? ...

Comment: maybe put your query in a list and then do the string joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `serialNumbers` is a local list, that wouldn't work anyhow if `DB.InventoryItems` is a queryable database table. You cannot join database tables with local collections. You shouldn't write it that way.

You should write it as:

```
var ids =
    from i in DB.InventoryItems
    where serialNumbers.Contains(i.SerialNumber)
    select i.id;
```

If you are then getting that error about too many items, that's a limitation of your database so you'll have to break that query out into smaller parts if you want to use that list of numbers. Otherwise you will have to eat the cost of filtering locally in a traditional foreach loop or casting to `IEnumerable`.